# How to create a new empty action?

Tags: animation

In action editor every time i press + it creates a new action but keeps the stuff inside the action i'm currently editing. Is it possible to create a completely empty action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's very easy. Just add fake user to your current action for it to be saved and then remove it from action editor by clicking on x and then click New.Like this:
[image]